# Continue statement not working properly in JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, continue

I am trying to use `continue` to omit `test3` from being used the total average.

I am not sure what Im doing wrong here. The goal is to use all of the array except for the numbers entered in the `test3` text box.

I am trying to gather the sum of all of the array (not including `test3`) in order to come up with an average at the end of my code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 3 Activity</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Test Score Average</h1>
        <p>Insert your 5 test scores in the boxes below</p>

        <form action="">
            Test 1:
            <input type="text" name="test1" id=t1>
            <br> Test 2:
            <input type="text" name="test2" id=t2>
            <br> Test 3:
            <input type="text" name="test3" id=t3>
            <br> Test 4:
            <input type="text" name="test4" id=t4>
            <br> Test 5:
            <input type="text" name="test5" id=t5>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate Average" onclick="calculateFunction()">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateFunction() {
                var test1 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
                var test2 = document.getElementById("t2").value;
                var test3 = document.getElementById("t3").value;
                var test4 = document.getElementById("t4").value;
                var test5 = document.getElementById("t5").value;
                var nums = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5];

                var totalSum = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                    totalSum += parseInt(nums[i]);

                    if (nums[i] === test3) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                var average = totalSum / nums.length;

                document.write("Test score average is " + average);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use `var nums = [test1, test2, test4, test5];`?

Comment: you need to put the conditional before the averaging.

Comment: You put the test after adding the value, the test should come before

Comment: I suspect this is because test3 contains a string, not a number. In which case either `if (nums[i] == test3)` or `if (nums[i] === parseInt(test3, 10))` would do the trick.

Comment: What result are you seeing? If you do `console.log(nums[i] === test3)` what do you get? As an observation, you are not parsing test3 to an int like you do with the other numbers. Try `if (nums[i] === parseInt(test3)){`. Also you put the adding before your conditional check.

Comment: Problem with your approach is if any test had same score as the test3, they would all be skipped.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, it was a requirement that I had to use a continue statement with a loop for an assignment I have. Thanks for all the help everyone, I really appreciate how fast the responses are on this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix is to move the `if` statement above where you add the value to `totalSum`, like so:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] === test3){
      continue;
    }
    totalSum += parseInt(nums[i]);
  }
```

However, this really isn't a good solution.  For example, what if all the numbers in your array are equal to 5?  Your average would be 0 since we would hit the `continue` every time.  If your goal is to always omit the third element in the array when calculating the average, something like this would be better:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i === 2) {
      continue;
    }
    totalSum += parseInt(nums[i]);
  }
```

Remember to divide by `nums.length - 1` since you're omitting one of the elements when calculating the average.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong now, youve been a great help to me, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  // get all the inputs you want to use
  let ts = document.querySelectorAll("#t1,#t2,#t4,#t5");

  let total = 0;
  // loop through the inputs and total them
  for (let t of ts) {

    // convert the value to an integer
    let value = parseInt(t.value);

    // check to ensure it is a number and matches with the person put in
    if (!isNaN(value) && value == t.value) {
      total += parseInt(t.value);
    } else {
      t.value = 'Ignored';
    }
  }
  let average = total / ts.length;

  document.getElementById("output").textContent = "Test score average is " + average;

});
```

```html
<h1>Test Score Average</h1>
<p>Insert your 5 test scores in the boxes below</p>


Test 1: <input type="text" name="test1" id=t1><br> Test 2: <input type="text" name="test2" id=t2><br> Test 3: <input type="text" name="test3" id=t3><br> Test 4: <input type="text" name="test4" id=t4><br> Test 5: <input type="text" name="test5" id=t5><br>

<!-- Use a button rather than an input -->
<button id="go" type="button">Calculate Average</button>

<output id="output"></output>
```

Comment: I appreciate the work you put into helping me here! It was a requirement that I use a continue statement, I should have specified that but going through your code, I see theres a great deal I dont know yet haha. thank you!

Comment: I’m sorry my answer didn’t help you.

A better use of the *continue* in this exercise would have been to loop through all the elements and ignore (continue over) those with missing or invalid data.